# Large image view with manipulation capabilities

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to find a simple tutorial for using an image view within my activity that does these things below, but I've not had any luck in finding one as the ones I've come across are too complicated and don't make finding the necessary code to implement easy. I have 1 XML (activity_map.xml) and 1 Java class (MapActivity.java). Does anyone know any?

- Panning
- Two finger pinch to zoom
- Double tap to zoom in and out
- Panning while zoomed in
- Set a maximum zoom level
- Use a large image for all of the above

**My XML code so far**

```
<com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.MapImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Please do not refer me to these samples as they do not work properly/are not what I'm looking for:

https://github.com/moagrius/TileView

https://github.com/johnnylambada/WorldMap

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into TouchImageView: https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

To use https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Add to build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
    ...
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.1.3'
}
```

Default layout file 'activity_main.xml':

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.cincinnatinight));
}
```

Comment: Does not work. I get out for memory error. `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 353329500 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM`

Comment: how big is the image you are trying to load? if the 353329500 byte is what you are tying to load, test with a scaled down version of the image

Comment: I don't want to scale down as my image contains a lot detail that is more legible when zoomed in. What's the biggest size I can use with that code?

Comment: I am not sure, but when the OOM error was thrown your app only had 1048576 bytes free.

Comment: Can something be changed to the code so that my activity behaves the same way this sample does? `https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view` where the image is subsampled.

Comment: what doesn't work about that library? do you not know how to implement it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77349/discussion-between-leibreichb1-and-macaronlover).